# Create a direct DATE or DATE/TIME input for iPhone apps

Tags: datetime, ios4, user-interface, xamarin.ios, uidatepicker

My users despise the iPhone native date/datetime pickers (spinning wheels).  I need to come up with another solution such as a custom UITableViewCell that allows direct input or a UIAlertView that is customized for input similar to the way Android handles date and time input.  I'll obviously need to validate the input as they input it to ensure it is a valid date and time input, as I'm using MonoTouch I suppose I'll use RegEx to validate.

Before I do all this work I'm looking for any feedback from others that may have tried this or references to other implementations so I can learn from someone that's already created a system such as this.

What suggestions do you have for handling date/time input on an iPhone/iPad app that does NOT use the native UIDateTimePicker?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I ported/created a Calendar controller that works pretty much like the calendar app. One previous app that I worked on used it and the users really liked it: https://github.com/escoz/monotouch-controls/blob/master/UICatalog/CalendarMonthViewController.cs

That doesn't address time input, but it might be worthy taking a look.

Comment: Thank you Eduardo - nice work.  Have you considered an iPad implementation?  My app is a universal app so I need to ensure my implementation works well on both platforms.

Comment: I haven't updated that code for a while.. I'm planning on working on it again soon, but no idea when that will be.